# How to combine two lists having duplicate values into a dictionary using python

Tags: python, list

Consider these two lists:

```
a = [1,2,2,4,4,5,6]
b = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6]
```

My desired output is:

```
{1:1, 2:2, 2:3, 4:4, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6}
```

But, using `dict(zip(a,b))` seems to remove duplicate values in a: I get `{1: 1, 2: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6}`.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Using `zip` correctly does not remove duplicates.

Comment: Your output is neither a dictionary nor any other Python data structure. What exactly do you expect as output?

Comment: `c = list(zip(a,b)` gives a list with exactly the tuples in your output. But in the title you talk about converting to a dictionary: if you want to have e.g. `a` items as keys and `b` items as values then it is not possible - dicts cannot have duplicate keys

Comment: The dictionary you say you want, `{1:1, 2:2, 2:3, 4:4, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6}` *is not possible* because dictionary keys are by definition unique. If it were possible, what would you expect `mydict[2]` to return, `2` or `3`? And why?

Answer (score 2):

This will give you a list of tuples, so you will keep the "duplicates":

```
a = [1,2,2,4,4,5,6]
b = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6]
output = list(zip(a,b))
```

**output :**

```
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (4, 4), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6)]
```

But if you do:

```
output = dict(zip(a,b))
```

you wil get :

```
{1: 1, 2: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6}
```

That's because **a `dict` structure can't have duplicate keys**. This data structure is made to map **unique** keys to values (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

So, you won't be able to get something like this:

```
{1:1, 2:2, 2:3, 4:4, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6}
```

But here is a workaround : you can use a `defaultdict` where each key is associated to a `list` or a `set`, like this :

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [1,2,2,4,4,5,6]
b = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6]

# We create a defaultdict with a list as its default_factory 
# (see link below for the documentation)
list_of_tuples = list(zip(a,b))

output = defaultdict(list)

# Here we wil create the "key: value" pairs of the defaultdict
# For each tuple in the list, 
# use the first item to create the unique key if needed 
# and append the second item to the value (which is a list)
for k,v in list_of_tuples:
    output[k].append(v)

print(output)
```

**output :**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [1], 2: [2, 3], 4: [4, 4], 5: [5], 6: [6]})
```

Documentation about defaultdict : https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a list :

```
a,b  = [1,2,2,4,4,5,6] ,[1,2,3,4,4,5,6]


ab = list(zip(a,b))

print(ab)
```

output :

```
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (4, 4), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6)]
```